# Webpack not making JS modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I want to make vanilla js/bootstrap website and I am using webpack. I have been following various instructions and tutorials but they do not seem to work.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    auth: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/auth.js'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/msal-2.28.1.js')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  entry: {
    main: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/index.js'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/api.js')
    ]
  },
  output: {  
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 3000,
    hot: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [
                  require('autoprefixer')
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But the error I get when I run webpack is:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'auth' in '/Users/me/Projects/AProject/src/js'
Did you mean './auth'?
```

All of the .js files exist where they should:

[Image of JS files in correct folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40VEW.png)

So I am at a loss as to what is going on. If I remove the second entry point (main) it builds fine no errors.

I have treid following every single tutorial and guide I can find and it just doesn't work.

Comment: Because JavaScript doesn't allow duplicate keys, the latter `entry` will override the former one. There's not enough information to tell more than that.

Comment: One option is that some module like `src/js/msal-2.28.1.js` has an import like `import auth from 'auth'`. At least that's what the error is implying.

Comment: Hi @JuhoVepsäläinen I have seen many tutorials doing multiple entries so what do you mean?

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen ah yes api.js imports auth.js could it be that?

Comment: You have structure like this: `{ entry: { ... }, output: { ... }, entry: { ... } }`. In JavaScript, latter will win.

Comment: "ah yes api.js imports auth.js could it be that?"

Exactly, that's what the error is telling. Likely it would need `./auth` at the import or so.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen yes that fixed it by removing that import. So the two entries should build 2 modules right? Are you saying there can only be one entry? Because all the tutorials and stuff that I follow they make multiple entries to combine various JS files into combined bundles.

Comment: That's from JavaScript specification. You can of course have `{ entry: { auth: [...], main: [...] } }`.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen I can't mark your answer as correct because it's a comment not an answer

Comment: No probs. That's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Juho Vepsäläinen

There were two errors occuring:

1. I had an import for auth.js in api.js
2. I have multiple entry: points and apparently JS will only use the last one.

Here is working config:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    auth: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/auth.js'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/msal-2.28.1.js')
    ],
    main: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/index.js'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/api.js')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 3000,
    hot: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [
                  require('autoprefixer')
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```